# Failed to add/activate connection

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop, the wifi is connecting to my home wifi as usual but whenever somebody uses my laptop in guest mode, it's not connecting to the wifi. It shows this error.

> Failed to add or activate connection.
>
> (0) Active connection could not be attached to the device.

Comment: Try this   ' open terminal and login as root then add a new connection and connect it'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **Edit Connections...** on network manager applet, select your wifi connection.

[image]

Enable **all users may connect to this network**

[image]

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)** (Copied from [Fabby's canned comment](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15559258/))

Comment: Ya did it already bro, says since I have reputation below 10 points....... Dunno what it meant hehe, anyways I did click on that up arrow

Comment: I happen to have the connectivity problem except that I am the admin and only user of my Ubuntu